# Google Sheet: search for text in a cell, if true returns a value, if false returns 0

Tags: google-sheets-formula

```
[1/28/2023,$5]Description
```

In my google sheet, a cell of a column has above value. I simply want to search "$5" in the cell, if it exists, then returns 5, otherwise returns 0.

```
=iferror(if(search("$5",N25)>0,5,0),0)
```

This is the formula I have managed to write. But it feels like it is redundant. Is there any better solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well if you wish to hardcode the value then try:

```
=IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\$(5)"),0)
```

if its to extract **N** value attached to **$** then try:

```
=IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\$(\d+)"),0)
```

- 

[image]

Comment: I am making it simple so even the amount is hardcoded because there will be only two amounts. `ifna` is the what I am looking for, chatgpt is at capacity so... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2, "\$(5)")*5
```